# How to print empty spaces in first column using awk or sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Here is my sample input file.

`ip.txt`:

```
john    math
        science
paul    math
        science
rosy    math
jill    science
rob     math
        science
hary    math
```

Desired output:

```
john

paul

rosy
jill
rob

hary
```

When I use:

```
awk '{print $1}' ip.txt
```

My output is:

```
john
science
paul
science
rosy
jill
rob
science
hary
```

I don not want the second column values printed, I want the blank spaces to be printed out to a file.

How can I achieve this? I am using Solaris 5.10 with `ksh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

awk:

```
awk '{print (NF>1) ? $1 : ""}' file
```

If the number of fields is more than 1, print the first field, otherwise print an empty line.

A couple of extra thoughts:

- If your data is tab-separated, then

  ```
  awk -F '\t' '{print $1}' file
  ```
- If you want to extract the first 8 characters

  ```
  awk '{print substr($0,1,8)}' file
  ```

Answer (score 1):

With POSIX sed:

```
sed -e 's/^\([^[:blank:]]*\)[[:blank:]].*/\1/;t' -ed <file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the extra spaces before the subject field, you can do:

```
grep -o "^[^ ]* \+" ip.txt
```

If you don't want the extra spaces:

```
sed 's/ \+.*//' ip.txt
```

Both of these will preserve lines with empty name fields.

Comment: +.  The `sed` one is actually smarter as it preserves even empty lines but probably the fastest solution would be `cut -d' ' -f1 ip.txt` (assuming spaces).